# Multi-Category Dropdown using react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I want to use react-select for a multi-category dropdown list. My use-case is to be able to select one option **at max** from each category. I have explained the given an example below where I want one item at max selected from each category. So we may have a selection like C1I1, C2I3, and C3I1. The project I have is using react-select v2.4.4 with react v15.6.2 and material-ui. Can anyone let me know how can I implement this functionality. Also, if this is already implemented or answered, please direct me towards it.

1. Category 1

- C1I1
- C1I2
- C1I3

2. Category 2

- C2I1
- C2I2
- C2I3
- C2I4

3. Category 3

- C3I1
- C3I2

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Created a reference pen.
https://codepen.io/chris495b/pen/QWKmXKE

While implementing the select component please dont forget to add isMulti attribute and also include data in the formate shared in the link for grouping.

```
<Select
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        isMulti
        defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
        options={groupedOptions}
        formatGroupLabel={formatGroupLabel}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But this is allowing multiple selections in each category. My requirement is to allow at max 1 selection from each category. What changes are needed to have this feature?

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my code. Just a little bit refactoring needs to be done `handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };` where the we get the selected option and set the current state.